# How to subtract time and date in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am uploading Bio-Metric data to my MYSQL database table.I am using PHP Codeigniter. In here i have the IN-TIME and OUT-TIME of a employee. But the employee may login and go out for some work and again come back in. So what i want is to select his first **login** and his last **logout** from my database. Now i have a dump for all days of the month!

So how to fetch the first login of the employee and his last logout?

My Table is as below:[image: Datatable]
Now the EMP_ID is the user-id ,date_data is the date and entry contains his in or out information.

If The entry>100 its called intime and else it in logout

This is my Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `daily_data2` (
          `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `emp_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
          `date_data` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
          `abc` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
          `def` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
          `entry` int(10) NOT NULL,
          `ghi` int(10) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3720 ;
```

So how to filter the data and get only my first login and last logout?
  This is My DATA:

[image: data]

Comment: Can you create the sql fiddle?

Comment: what should i be posting in it? @SanjayKumarNS

Comment: what is entry = 3 mean ??

Comment: You can create the table schema

Comment: That would be considered as Login @bluesky any entry above 100 is logout and below it is login

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b70df

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS i have also added my schema in my question

Comment: If the sql fiddle is there more users can have a try there.

Comment: i have added the fiddle i guess that might work@SanjayKumarNS http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b70df

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS  if entry>100 its called intime and else it in logout

Comment: You want it for each days?

Comment: I want to show a month's view in which i can see for each user who logged in at what time and logged out at what time

Comment: I have created another table called users in which i have added the names of each emplyoee and have manually inserted Emp_id against each of them

Comment: @Rajan why do you store your date_data as Varchar? you better change it to date, if working with queries

Comment: I saved it as varchar because as you i am uploading my data from text file and if i keep it as date it showed me error @IlanHasanov Moreover it has date and time

Comment: can this help me: SELECT daily_data2.entry, users.emp_id, users.name FROM  daily_data2, users WHERE daily_data2.emp_id = users.emp_id;

Comment: For now i just want a emp_id's first login and his last logout to be fetched from database how to do thata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will return one record from the database per employe. the record will be the first and last in the last 24 hours. you can switch between `desc` and `asc` for the newest or oldest result. you can also store the `ORDER BY` as `@param` and call it two times.

```
class YOUR_MODEL extends CI_Model {

public $time = '';

/**
 * @param $emp_id
 * getting the first & last login in the last 24 hours from the database.
 * results are limited to one and can be ordered by ASC, or DESC
 */
function get_attendance_history($emp_id) {

    $hours = $this->time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 day', time()));
    //desc will print the newest records && asc the latest.
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM daily_data2 WHERE emp_id = '{$emp_id}' AND date_data > '{$hours}' ORDER BY `date_data` desc LIMIT 1";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql); //run the query
    print_r( $result->result_array() ); //debug the result
    //return $result->row()->emp_id; //for one record show..
    exit;

    }
}
```

#### Usage in Controller:

```
public function test() {

    $this->load->model('test_m');
    $emp_id = '33'; //your emp_id
    $rajan = $this->test_m->get_attendance_history($emp_id);

}
```

Comment: what should be my controller??

Comment: i did this: public function test($emp_id)
    {
        $this->load->model('test_m');
        $rajan = $this->test_m->get_attendance_history();
    }

Comment: shows me error for Message: Missing argument 1 for Test_M::get_attendance_history(), called in C:\wamp\www\trial\application\controllers\admin\attendance.php on line 51 and defined

Comment: i got a blank array Array ( )

Comment: Did you changed the number 33 to a proper number from your database? from the screen shot i can see for example the number 1

Comment: yeah i changed it  $emp_id = '1';

Comment: try $emp_id = 1; without the qoutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98089/discussion-between-rajan-and-ilan-hasanov).

Comment: a last question! How do i know which the first login and last login of a user for s single  day. i knw its too broad but see if you can help me